# URL tags not converted to <a> HTML tags

Tags: wysiwyg, input-formats

I have been using CKEditor, but didn't like the table editing capabilities so attempted to move to TinyMCE.  Having done this, all links now appear as plain text in the following format :

```
[url=http://somedomain.com/page]Page[/url]
```

It looks as if a filter has been dropped, or it is incorrectly configured, but I don't know how, or why. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the *BBCode* plugin in Tinymce settings.

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks for the concise and 100% correct answer!!